# 404 with long query string

Tags: datatable, codeigniter-3, query-string

I am using codeigniter. I am retrieveing data using datatable.

It works fine on my local pc. but on a remote server it causes 404 .
 The query string generated by datatable is too long causing 404.

If I reduce the query string length, it works perfectly.

.htcaccess content

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't application. Its the server I hosting my application.

It's IIS server  By default **Denies Request with too many query string**  .

I had to make web.config file and change the request limit parameter

```
  <security> 
    <requestFiltering> 
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="xxxx" /> 
    </requestFiltering> 
   </security>
```

Hope help some one else!!